# how to typedef a constant variable

Tags: c, typedef

```
  typedef char* ptr;
  const ptr p;
```

Which is true:

- `p` points to a constant character; or
- `p` is a constant and points to a character.

Please explain the reason

Comment: You could test it. http://ideone.com/SIYlz

Comment: nice example of the difference between `typedef` and `#define`

Comment: So, what answer does your C book give to this very basic question?

Answer (score 8):

```
typedef char* ptr;
const ptr p;
```

The latter line is equivalent to

```
char * const p;
```

i.e. `p` is a `const` pointer to `char`. The `typedef` introduces a new name for a type, it is not a textual substitution.

Answer (score 5):

First, let's take the typedef out of the equation for a moment.

`const char *p` and `char const *p` both declare `p` as a *non-const* pointer to *const* data; you can assign `p` to point to different things, but you cannot modify the thing being pointed to.

`char * const p` declares `p` as a *const* pointer to *non-const* data; you cannot change `p` to point to a different object, but you can modify the thing `p` is pointing to.

`const char * const p` and `char const * const p` both declare `p` as a *const* pointer to *const* data.  That should be fairly self-explanatory.

The `typedef` is a little non-intuitive. `ptr` is a synonym for `char *`, so `const ptr` acts as `char * const`; the `const` qualifier is being applied to the pointer type, not the `char` type.